# splice inside a loop doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript, loops, splice

I am looping to a json object, where  I have an array of objects.
I want to remove from my array, the objects with a null value on iban and with more than 12 digits on Account number. 
If both this conditions are met, I want to remove the item.
I have 3 items on my list that should be removed because those meet this conditions, yet only 2 are removed.

my function goes like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < benefs.length; i++) {
                var befNumberIban = benefs[i].Iban;
                var befNumber = benefs[i].AccountNumber;
  if (befNumber != null) {

    if (isBefLenght && (befNumberIban == null || befNumberIban == "")) {


        benefs.splice(i, 1);
```

I cant understand why it only removes 2 our 3 objects that meet the condition...something about splice?

Comment: You are removing values from array while iterating through that array. When you splice, length of that array is changing.

Comment: Do you update i when you make a splice ? You should decrement i by 1 as the index is not valid anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array will re-indexed, so for the last item i will be 1 and array length will be 1 too it will not go inside the loop and hence you are not getting the desire result inside for loop. You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve this easily.

```js
const benefs = [{
  Iban: null,
  AccountNumber: "",
}, {
  Iban: null,
  AccountNumber: "",
}, {
  Iban: null,
  AccountNumber: "",
}]

const isBefLenght = true;
var newArray = benefs.filter(a => {
  return isBefLenght && !(a.Iban === null || a.befNumberIban === "");
})

console.log(newArray);
```